# Is it possible to view unnamed frame / function argument with GDB?

Tags: c++, gdb, coredump

When I have a core dump (after segfault) and the frame I am interested in looks like this:

```
#2  0x000000000043cbfa in foo::Bar::baz(float) ()
```

How do I extract the argument value in the given frame with GDB?

Comment: You can try manually examining stack frame (info frame, info reg, x/<x>x $sp...). It looks debug info is missing for this function, so you might have to disassemble the code and try to understand what's happening.

Comment: The name of the function has enough information for me. I just want to know the argument value. The question is basically if I can get the valuye without actually disassembling the code. I have basic knowledge of gdb and quick googling gave me no results.

Comment: Not without also knowing where that argument is stored at the time of crash - e.g. it may be in a register, on the stack, depending on the calling convention and current state in the function. Nobody knows without knowing at least what processor and what OS (and may depend on what compiler and what optimisation level is used too)

Comment: @MatsPetersson And is there any online source I can go through to learn about those things? (Btw. it is amd64, glibc cpp.)

Comment: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/

Answer (score 0):

Going off memory. Command sequence to list the argument in a frame are

```
frame 2
info args
```

Comment: That ends up with *"No symbol table info available."*

Comment: Do you have debug symbols for that code? Can you get such a version? If you can, you can use "symbol-file" command to load symbols and if function was not heavily optimized it should work.

Comment: I guess that is the crux of the question: *How to get the value without it having a symbol assigned?*

Comment: A combination of `disassemble`, `info registers` and `x` perhaps? (And of course understanding the actual code)

Comment: Without a symbol table those commands won't work, as others have stated. You'll need to dive into the assembly to get the info you need.